# How to add emphasis without using profanity

Tags: word-choice, offensive-language

My son uses *fuck* or *fucking* to emphasize his statements. I told him there are words that you can use that aren't so offensive for my 3 year old grandchild to parrot!  He asked what word is so globally understood to add emphasis. Also, I am looking for a list of words.

Comment: Perhaps a few minced oaths, such as: *Holy cow*, *holy smoke*, *bloody Mary*, *bloody nora* (BrEng),  *darn right*, *for Pete's sake* or *goddammit*, the latter might be considered equally offensive by some, but I'd consider it less bothersome than *fuck*. Here's a list, but some expressions are more colourful than others http://www.lutins.org/lists/minced_oaths.html There's always the Irish *feckin'*

Comment: Young people who use "fuck" a lot don't go in for minced oaths.

Comment: @Robusto true but in front of a three-year-old (his son?) he should be adult enough to be able to restrain himself.

Comment: @Robusto , @ FumbleFingers  ,All the members should be polite and use polite words .

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Easier said than done when you hit your thumb with a hammer. ^_^

Comment: @Rwy5: There is a difference between using them and talking about them. We are talking about them here, and it is the province of this site to do so.

Comment: @Robusto, You're right, however I think *the end does not justify the means*.

Comment: You can't a worthwhile discussion of profanity in language without using profanity. And one person's "frick" is another person's "fuck": the euphemisms soon become offensive to the more easily offended among us.

Comment: In the US,  "freak" and "freaking" are often used in mixed company.  "Frigging," (which is the original expression) is almost completely unknown to the younger generation.  As an older person, I find "freaking" annoying, so I have tried to replace my "F-word" reflex with "smurf" and "smurfing" - still waiting for it to catch on...

Comment: 'Listen carefully, I will say this only once.'

Comment: @Rwy5: I think inevitably if we're going to be *referencing* ***fuck*** as embodying the "quintessence" of the sought-for alternative, it's inevitable the word will actually appear here. To my mind that raises the bar for OTT usages in comments. Not that I *mind* my comment having been summarily deleted (it's all ephemera), but in my opinion (and in context), ***very fucking*** constitutes more of a "mention" than a "use", since I was primarily simply proposing ***very*** as a candidate alternative. Ho hum.

Comment: @Oldbag: That particular "euphemism" is probably already way past its smurfing sell-by date, given Family Guy were already taking the smurf out of it [back in 2001](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080415200906AAqSYjF).

Comment: The replacement word I learned from a policeman is **stinkin'** (or **stinking**).  It works great. --- Some people are able to replace the problematic word with *F-ing* but for most people it's too close to the original to be effective.  ---  You can also brainstorm with the child to come up with something silly.  The year my son got in trouble with a ridiculously strict counselor at summer camp for saying "What the heck?" we decided together on "What the piano?!" as a replacement, and it worked great, because every time I reminded him of our agreement by saying "What the piano?!" he laughed.

Comment: You can convey self-censorship by replacing words that are too rude to say in certain situations with _bleep_ and _bleeping_, as the case may be. This has the advantage of indicating that the censored word is not suitable for delicate ears while retaining the vehemence—together with the form of the part of speech (noun, verb, or modifier)—that made it spring to mind in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

May I be so bold to suggest that it's not emphasis but ***[restraint](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/restraint)*** that is called for here? Raising children myself I know how easy it is to transfer bad habits without meaning to.

Children should be enabled to acquire these bad habits later-on as an adult or at least after puberty sets in.

> Definition of restraint in English:
>   noun
>   Unemotional, dispassionate, or moderate behaviour; self-control:
>   *'he urged the protesters to exercise restraint'*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/restraint

Comment: agreed.  Even if parents think it's OK for their kids to grow up in a profanity-laden household, below a certain age those kids won't know when and where it's OK to swear.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what the exact circumstances are, but when every third word someone utters is "fuck" or "fucking" it's not for "emphasis".  In fact the the ability of the word to "emphasize" is lost when used with such frequency.  What they're demonstrating is an inability/unwillingness to think clearly about what they intend to say.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: My mother always said Fudge - everyone likes fudge.  :)

Answer (score -1):

"**Fucking**" as an adjective or adverb can often be replaced by "very". Eg. "It is fucking hot" means "it is very hot". Therefore you can replace "fucking" with more elaborate adjectives such as "extremely", "amazingly" or "incredibly".

"**Fuck**" can also be used as an arbitrary exclamation, and can be replaced by something colloquial like "wow" or "crikey". Eg. "Fuck, it's hot" means "Wow, it's hot".